ENS: Resolve NFT to its name
When registering an ENS name, an NFT is received corresponding to the name. Given I know the token ID and contract address of the NFT, how can I determine the corresponding ENS name for it (e.g. foo.eth)?
For example what is the ideal implementation for this hypothetical function:
const name = await getENSName({
  contractAddress: '0x57f1887a8BF19b14fC0dF6Fd9B2acc9Af147eA85',
  tokenId: '79233663829379634837589865448569342784712482819484549289560981379859480642508'
})

console.log(name) // "vitalik.eth"

I would like a solution that only relies on querying an ethereum node directly, and does NOT require any of the following:

Parsing logs on multiple txs - I found this dune query that gets me what I want, but recreating this as RPC calls to an eth node would be too slow.
Hitting 3rd party APIs such as OpenSea

Given that the ENS "NFTs" were deployed before metadata became standardized, they don't contain a tokenURI. And since the tokenIds are hashes of the labels, it's not feasible to compute it from the token ID.

After a bit more digging here's what I found (maybe someone can expand) - There are 2 registrars as of now:
The current registrar: 0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85
The "old" registrar: 0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5
This works for the old one:
const OLD_ETH_REGISTRAR_CONTROLLER_ADDRESS = '0x283af0b28c62c092c9727f1ee09c02ca627eb7f5';
const oldAbi = [
  'event NameRegistered(string name, bytes32 indexed label, address indexed owner, uint256 cost, uint256 expires)'
]
async function getENSNameOldRegistrar(tokenId) {
  const tokenIdHex = ethers.BigNumber.from(tokenId)._hex;
  const logs = await provider.getLogs({
    address: OLD_ETH_REGISTRAR_CONTROLLER_ADDRESS,
    topics: [
      ethers.utils.id('NameRegistered(string,bytes32,address,uint256,uint256)'),
      tokenIdHex
    ],
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
  });
  if (!logs.length) return null;
  const log = logs[0];
  const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(oldAbi);
  const parsedLog = iface.parseLog(log);
  return parsedLog.args.name;
}

const name = await getENSNameOldRegistrar('22303645715405938737490451775665083008282466825917479642021483587739661596784')

if (name) {
  console.log(`${name}.eth`) // "9323.eth"
}


The NameRegistered event used to contain the actual name in the event, but the new one does not. Since the tokenId is essentially the hash of the ens name (and only these hashes are written on-chain) I don't see any feasible way of doing this using just the on-chain data. The Graph actually used a rainbow table to allow this to be queried using the hash so for now querying The ENS Subgraph or the ENS metadata API directly seems to be the way to do it. For querying the ENS metadata API just use the following endpoint:
https://metadata.ens.domains/mainnet/<contract_address>/<token_id>
